# Android FragmentTransaction() IllegalStateException: Fragment already added

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I am trying to show multiple fragments in a FrameLayout container. The basic idea is to use a spinner to select a different fragment to be displayed in the container. I am trying to add them programmatically and for this  I have created one xml file for each day of the week which is what I am trying to show.

```
    // Set up the spinner to select days of the week.
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) weekView.findViewById(R.id.day_selecter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int pos, long id) {
                // For each day of the week, create a new instance of Switches
                // get an instance of FragmentTransaction from your Activity
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                Fragment frag = fm.findFragmentByTag(Integer.toString(pos));
                if(frag == null) {
                    switch(pos) {
                        case 0: frag = new mondayFragment();
                                break;
                        case 1: frag = new tuesdayFragment();
                                break;
                        case 2: frag = new wednesdayFragment();
                                break;
                        case 3: frag = new thursdayFragment();
                                break;
                        case 4: frag = new fridayFragment();
                                break;
                        case 5: frag = new saturdayFragment();
                                break;
                        case 6: frag = new sundayFragment();
                                break;
                    }
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.week_program_switches, frag, Integer.toString(pos));
                }
                else
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.week_program_switches, frag, Integer.toString(pos));
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
```

The program manages to load the fragment corresponding to the first day of the week, i.e. the mondayFragment into the container. Each fragment contains textboxes and checkboxes so i need to save the view of each fragment loaded. At times the app would allow me to select a different day but the content from the previous fragment gets carried over and it eventually crashes the app with an IllegalStateException error: Day has already been added to fragment transaction. other times, simply selecting a different day in the spinner immediately crashes the app with the same error. I really need your help in this as I'm all out of ideas.

Few Notes:
1. I have not added any fragment statically into any layout. I have seen this to be the cause of many related issues.
2. I originally intended to use a single fragment and create multiple instances in a frameLayout container but i had similar issues of saving the content in each instance.

Comment: does this only crashed when you click on the same fragment twice?

Comment: I think I may have fixed by simply replacing the fragmentTransaction.add() with fragmentTransaction.replace(). Now, the content does not overlap and so far no crashes..fingers crossed